# hsql: how to execute script in a given path?

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I want to execute script in a given path, hsqldb (in memory). In PostgreSQL it can to do:

```
BEGIN;
\i create_test_table.sql
COMMIT;
```

How can to do it in hsqldb (in memory)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLTool to run scripts with HSQLDB.  (Doc URL updated 2016-07-27).

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#N109EC